# Retaining Scroll Position in Ember

Tags: jquery, css, ember.js, pushstate

I'm attempting to create an Ember app where the scroll positions between routes are retained providing the user with a more pleasant experience whilst browsing.

**Expected result**

If I scroll 500px down on /pageb, click a link to /pagea, click the browser back button I should be back at the 500px scroll top.

**Actual result**

When clicking the browser back button, the scroll top equals the height of /pagea.

**How to reproduce**

```
git clone https://github.com/eTilbudsavis/ember-scroll-demo
cd ember-scroll-demo
npm install
ember serve
open http://localhost:4200/pageb
```

Then you scroll all the way to the bottom, click the pagea link, and then click the browser back button, and you should see the issue.

**Final notes**

I think the reason for this behavior is when I click the browser back button, the browser tries to scroll back to the position it had before leaving that route. Because Ember hasn't rendered that view yet, the browser cannot go there. It can only scroll as far down as the height of /pagea.

Now, what's more tricky is, if I go to the console of the browser and manually set the scroll top after clicking back, nothing happens either. It seems the browser *thinks* it's at the right scroll top even though it isn't. If I do a single scroll with my mouse, the browser jumps all the way down to the place it was supposed to be at.

I hope I've explained this as concise as possible. Otherwise, feel free to ask for more details.

Thanks!

Comment: I updated my answer, it should now work in both Firefox and Chrome browsers.

Comment: another answer, with a mixin: http://reefpoints.dockyard.com/2014/05/05/preserve-scroll-position-in-ember-apps.html

Comment: I've tried that one but it doesn't really work properly particularly in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the question myself with this route mixin if anyone wants to use it:

```
`import Ember from 'ember'`

Ember.$(window).on 'unload', ->
    $(@).scrollTop 0

    return

PreserveScrollMixin = Ember.Mixin.create
    # @property [Integer] the time to wait before running the scroll callback
    #
    scrollingTimeout: 100

    # As soon as the route initializes, set the min height on the body and the scroll top on the window and listen to
    # future scroll events.
    #
    beforeModel: ->
        height = @getWithDefault 'controller.height', 0
        scrollTop = @getWithDefault 'controller.scrollTop', 0
        onScroll = =>
            Ember.run.debounce @, @runScrolled, @scrollingTimeout

            return

        Ember.$('body').css 'min-height', height
        Ember.$(window).on 'scroll.scrollable', onScroll
        Ember.$(window).scrollTop scrollTop

        return

    # When the route's model is ready, set the scroll top again to be sure.
    #
    afterModel: ->
        scrollTop = @getWithDefault 'controller.scrollTop', 0

        Ember.run.next @, ->
            Ember.$(window).scrollTop scrollTop

            return

        return

    # Sets the scroll top for the window.
    #
    runScrolled: ->
        @set 'controller.scrollTop', Ember.$(window).scrollTop()

        return

    actions:
        # When the route appears, allow the body to flow naturally.
        #
        didTransition: ->
            Ember.$('body').css 'min-height', '100%'

            return

        # When the route is about to leave, stop listening to scroll events and set the current body height.
        #
        willTransition: ->
            Ember.$(window).off 'scroll.scrollable'
            @set 'controller.height', Ember.$('body').height()

            return

`export default PreserveScrollMixin`
```

Comment: Now you're storing the scroll state inside the controller. If the controller is used many times throughout the app, there will be only one scroll state, right?

Comment: I've actually changed it a bit so that the scroll state isn't inside the controller. Instead it's in a global (a module) object called `scrollTops` where I persist changes like this: scrollTops[@routeName] = Ember.$(window).scrollTop().

Comment: The same issue remains, as you can now one store one scroll state per route, and not an individual scroll state per history item.

Answer (score 0):

You are seems trying to rely on browsers 'scroll state', but you didn't specify what browser are you using.

I've tried to create long page and to go to an external link, and current `Chrome` saved scroll state after return, but `Firefox` didn't.

So, without relying on browser, the general answer to 'state saving' question is to use [queryParams](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/).

I created sample with scroll state saved to queryParams. Note, that I'm using [replaceState](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/#toc_update-url-with-code-replacestate-code-instead) to prevent browser to create new history entry for every scroll.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    scrollTop: {
      replace: true
    }
  },
  setupController: function(controller) {
    $(window).on('load', function() {
      $(document).scrollTop(controller.get('scrollTop'));  
    });
  }
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  queryParams: ["scrollTop"],
  scrollTop: 0,
  handleScroll: function() {
    this.set('scrollTop', $(document).scrollTop());
  },
  bindScrollEvent: function() {
    $(window).on('scroll', Ember.run.bind(this, this.handleScroll));
  }.on('init')
});
```

JSBin is [here](http://jsbin.com/hayisaxixe/1/edit?html,js).

UPDATE: I replaced code sample with fixed version, which actually works in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it! I'm, however, a bit concerned about saving scroll state in the URL. I can't think of any website that does this? It's a bit confusing IMO to have the URL update on every scroll. Since asking my question I've been working on a potential solution: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b51b25ec8d1a36cba752. It's in CoffeeScript – I hope you don't mind. It seems to work in all browsers. What do you think?

Comment: It looks nice, however, I haven't understood from gist, where scroll state being saved (session, localStorage)?
Storing in URL can be useful, if you want to pass URL with stored scroll state to somebody else. I haven't seen any site that actually doing this. You may be first :)
Actually, it hard to do without Ember.

Comment: I actually don't want to save the scroll state for when you return to the website after visiting an external resource. I want wanted to make sure the website experience remembered the scroll position for every route going forward and backward.